# How to control size and color of textGeometry with dat.gui?

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I found out that I could use dat.gui to control size and color of textGeometry besides changing color and size for every other scene through editing .js file. But probably bad architecture of my code, I am not able to control or even add gui folder to the scene. It probably has something to do with FontLoader that I'm using.

I tried placing dat.gui inside and outside my textGeometry creation function, none of them worked. As far as I understood, every time size or color changes it should dispose and remove the created mesh to create a new one with the new color/size parameters (i also update for every each keydown event to create a new mesh so that's my thought).

*textGeometry, textMesh, textMaterial etc. are defined in global*

```
function textCreation() {
  const fontLoader = new FontLoader();
  fontLoader.load(
    "node_modules/three/examples/fonts/droid/droid_sans_bold.typeface.json",
    (droidFont) => {
      textGeometry = new TextGeometry(initText, { //initText variable gets updated with each keydown
        size: 5,
        height: 2,
        font: droidFont,
        parameters: {
          size: 5,
          height: 2,
        },
      });
      textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
      textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

      group = new THREE.Group();
      group.add(textMesh);
      scene.add(group);

    }
```

And here is the dat.gui controller that I tried to place in and out of this function.

```
let textFolder = gui.addFolder("Text Controls");
textFolder.add(textGeometry, "size", 10, 20).onChange(function () {
textGeometry.setSize(textGeometry.size);
// Probably dispose and remove old mesh from scene and create mesh with these new parameters
});

textFolder.addColor(textGeometry, "color").onChange(function () {
textGeometry.setColor(textGeometry.color);
```

I couldn't manage to add ANY dat.gui controller without breaking the scene. By the way I'm kinda new to JavaScript and three.JS so further explanations are welcome if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> textGeometry.setSize(textGeometry.size);

This does not work since there isn't a `setSize()` method. You have to call `dispose()` on the existing geometry and then create a new one based on your updated parameters. You then assign the new geometry to your text mesh. So something like:

```js
const params = {
    color: '#ffffff',
    size: 5
};

textFolder.add(params, "size", 10, 20).onChange(function (value) {

    textGeometry.dispose();
    textGeometry = new TextGeometry(initText, {
            size: value,
            height: 2,
            font: droidFont
    });
    textMesh.geometry = textGeometry;

});
```

The material's color can be changed without creating a new object.

```js
textFolder.addColor(params, 'color').onChange(function (value) {

    textMaterial.color.set(value);

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I made changes according to your solution and it is working as expected now.